# How to set empty message for data table after click event>

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery data table to display fetched data from server. Some times there are no records available to display for given request, So in this condition I want to display message:

```
"Records are not available for your request".
```

For this initially i used:

```
"language" : {"emptyTable" : "Records are not available for your request"}
```

Problem with this is it act as default message where as I want to set default message

`"No data in table"`

and if records are not available then message should be

`"Records are not available for your request".`

So how can I set these two kind of message for my datatable

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not creating HTML like:

```
 <table style="width: 100%; padding-top: 15px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="cols" border="1" style="border-color: #71A8D2; border-width: 1px; border-style: Solid; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr class="common" align="center" style="height: 100px;">
                                                                    <td colspan="8">Records are not available for your request.</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="height: 100%; padding-bottom: 15px;">&nbsp;
                                                            &nbsp;
                                                            &nbsp;

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

default display should be none. If `Datatable` null then show this table and hide main table.

Comment: Thanx for your reply :).. Me too thought about this option but I can't use this option.. is there any way available where I can set these two type of messages for data table??

Comment: ok, can you update your question with some jquery code which you are using to check datatable null or not?